# jQuery .animate .stop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

My "stop" button does not work properly. Usually the first time the animation keeps going and then it works after that. I'd also like to know how to return the div's height when stop is clicked and display it.

```
//HTML
<div id = "wrapper">
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "meter"></div>
</div>
<button id ="start">START</button>
<button id ="stop">STOP</button>
</div>

//CSS
#wrapper {
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#container {
    height: 300px; width: 60px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#meter {
    height: 0;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

//Javascript
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#start').on('click', function () {
        for(var i = 0; i<100; i++) {    
            $("#meter").animate({height:300}, 1000);
            $("#meter").animate({height: 0}, 1000);
            $('#stop').on('click', function () {  
                $("#meter").stop();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2p3xj01j/

Comment: `$("#meter").stop(true, true);`

Comment: Thanks, adding just the first "true" works. The second parameter jumps to the end, which is not what I was looking for. How could I then display the height? I think I can get it by "$(this).height();" right? But how to display it to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can understand that you want to chain 200 animations on `#meter` in the `for-loop`. But with your code you additionally create 300 jQuery-objects and attaches 100 times the same click-handler. You should move some code out of the loop.

Create an element to display the height in your HTML just before #container:

```
<div id = "display">Display height</div>
```

And your JS could look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var meter = $("#meter"); // create jQuery-object once and store it

$('#start').on('click', function () { // setup for the start-button
    // create 200 animations
    for(var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
        // reference to the variable and chain the jQuery functions  
        meter.animate({height:300}, 1000).animate({height: 0}, 1000);
    }
});

$('#stop').on('click', function () { // setup for the stop-button separate
    // stop animations, clear animation queue, get height of meter, get display-element
    // set its content to the meter height, and all that with one line
    $("#display").html(meter.stop(true).height());
});

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2e7uyzta/4/).

**VERSION 2:** Instead of chaining 200 animations you can use the `complete-callback` of `.animate()` to recursivly call an animation function, so it runs in an infinite loop (stoppable of course as above):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var meter = $("#meter");

function run() { // define a function that runs only two animations
    // second animation gets a 'callback' to 'run' so after finishing
    // function 'run' is called again
    meter.animate({height:300}, 1000).animate({height: 0}, 1000, run);
}

$("#start").click(run); // START calls function 'run'

$('#stop').on('click', function () { // STOP is same as above
    $("#display").html(meter.stop(true).height());
});

});
```

Details about using callbacks in the [**.animate() reference**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Thank you, Martin. Instead of having the for loop go through 200 animations, how could I make it loop until the stop button is clicked?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer See VERSION 2 in my answer.